# Рекурсивный поиск js возвращает undefined

Tags: javascript, алгоритм, рекурсия, undefined-reference

Я пробовал поиграться с дебагером, итерация находит нужный мне объект но почему-то проходит мимо, не могу понять в чём причина.

```js
function recursive_search(obj, target) {
  for (let key in obj) {
    if (obj[key] === target) return obj[key];
    recursive_search(obj[key], target);
  }
}

const obj1 = {
  obj2: {},
  obj3: {
    obj5: {},
    obj6: {
      value: "key"
    },
    obj7: {},
  },
  obj4: {},
};

recursive_search(obj1, 'key');
```

Некоторые в комментариях пишут что я результат никуда не сохраняю хотя не понял зачем это если его можна вернуть сразу как я и делал
Я попробовал изменить код вод так

```js
function recursive_search(obj, target) {
  let result;

  for (let key in obj) {
    if (obj[key] === target) result = obj[key];
    recursive_search(obj[key], target);
  }

  return result;
}
```

Но это лишь вызвало ошибку переполнение стека.

Comment: У вас с результатом рекурсивного вызова ничего не происходит, вы его не записываете никуда даже. То есть найти то нашли, а вернуть куда то забыли.

Comment: Какой-то бессмысленный поиск. Вот вы нашли что что-то равно target и тут же вернули это «что-то». Но какой в это смысл если оно равно target который мы уже знаем?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Когда recursive_search вызывается внутри, то её результат "сгорает". Надо его чему-то присваивать и тоже возвращать.

P.s. Заменила "return obj[key]" на просто "return key" чтобы видеть имя ключа, а не его значение, которые мы и так знаем, так как ищем его.

```js
function recursive_search(obj, target) {
  for (let key in obj) {
    if (obj[key] === target)
        return key;
    else {
        let res = recursive_search(obj[key], target);
        if (res) {
        return res;
      }
    }
  }
}

const obj1 = {
  obj2: {},
  obj3: {
    obj5: {},
    obj6: {
      value: "key"
    },
    obj7: {},
  },
  obj4: {},
};

console.log(recursive_search(obj1, 'key'))
```

Comment: Спасибо, всё заработало))